# When is horizontal composition of natural transformation used?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading [Leinster's book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) and at the end of Section 1.3 he defines horizontal composition of natural transformations. I don't see any motivation for this definition, and the only application the author mentions is the construction of some functor $[\mathscr A',\mathscr A'']\times[\mathscr A,\mathscr A']\to[\mathscr A,\mathscr A'']$, which I'm not sure why I should care about.

On the other hand, it is clear why one needs the vertical composition -- at least to define composition in the functor category; and because of this I find the vertical composition quite an important notion.

My question is whether the horizontal composition is as important as the vertical one (e.g. is it used as frequently? If I skip this part of the text, will I be able to understand the basics of adjoints/representables/limits?) and, if it's possible to answer assuming only the material up to Section 1.3 of the aforementioned book, where/how can it be used?

Comment: Horizonal composition is used all the time, though usually in the special case of whiskering. That is, given $\alpha:F\to G$, we have $id_H*\alpha:HF\to HG$ and $\alpha*id_K:FK\to GK$. These are typically written as $H\alpha$ and $\alpha_K$ and are omnipresent. We can get general horizontal composition for $\alpha:F\to G$ and $\beta:H\to K$ via $\alpha_K\circ F\beta=\alpha*\beta=G\beta\circ \alpha_H:FH\to GK$.

Comment: If you want a specific example of what Derek says, you may want to look at adjunctions, where this whiskering thing appears constantly; and since adjunctions are omnipresent, so is whiskering.  More generally, it is super intuitive to evaluate a functor on a natural transformation, or to restrict a natural transformation along a functor, so this whiskering operation (and therefore the horizontal composition) should make intuitive sense